# How to log data values in a while loop?

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to log data values in each loop. My issue is that the code only logs one entry instead of the new TF and TC value each 0.5 second. My relevant code is:

```
import time  
import math 
import os  
from time import strftime
import string
while True:
    Vmid = chan0.voltage
    Vthermistor = (Vsource - Vmid)
    Current = Vmid/Rfixed
    Rthermistor = Vthermistor / Current
    Ratio = Rthermistor / Rref
    print(' Vmid = %6.2f Vthermistor = %6.2f  Current = %8.4e' % (Vmid , Vthermistor, Current))
    X = math.log(Ratio)
    TK = 1/(A1 + B1*X + C1*X*X + D1*X*X*X)
    TC = TK - 273.15
    TF = TC * 1.8 + 32
    print(' Temperatures deg K %6.2f  deg C %6.2f   deg F %6.2f\n' % (TK, TC, TF))
    # hang out and do nothing for a half second
    log = open('log.txt', 'w') #open a text file for logging
    log.write('%s,%f,%f' % (strftime("%H:%M"), TF, TC)) #write to log
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `open()` mode from `w` (write, where file will be overwritten each time) to `a` (append).

Also, generally speaking you wanna open the file once, since you're not closing it after writing, so open it before the loop, write in the loop, flush and close it after the loop.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to format my log file nicely in a format friendly to .CSV software like Excel?

Comment: Well, you are already formatting it in a CSV form :) There are CSV libraries, but for as simple a use-case as this I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Is there a way to print this info so there is a time column, TF column, and a TC column in excel? If I use the colon as a delimiter the time gets messed up and I have columns that are time, tf, tc instead of separate columns. Apologies for the noob question

Comment: Not a massive excel guru here, what happens if you quote the time? i.e. `'"%s",%f,%f'`?

Comment: I get "13:18",76.359470,24.644150,"13:18",76.359470,24.644150,

Comment: You mean you miss linebreaks? Add `\n` in the end of the format, i.e. `log.write('%s,%f,%f\n'....)`